# new models that I add aren't detected in the migrations

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I deployed a website on python anywhere. Then I planed on adding an extra model for more functionality. I added that model offline and it works fine but when I made changes to the deployed website the bash console didn't detect any migrations. I thought there was something wrong with the model so I added some sample models to check but even those weren't getting detected when I used 
`python manage.py makemigrations`

the same happened when I used 
`python manage.py migrate` I read up the docs but there isn't a problem with the code

Comment: Did you add the app where you defined the models to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I didn't add a new app I added a model to an existing app.

Comment: You shouldn’t be running `makemigrations` on your deployed site. Run `makemigrations` in your development environment and add the migrations into your repository. Then when you deploy, check out the latest release including the migrations and run `migrate`.

Comment: Try adding "--verbosity 3" as an argument to makemigrations to see if that can help you debug.